# (De)Serialize/deserialize MATLAB graph objects from and to Python

Tags: matlab, python-2.7, serialization, graph, deserialization

[MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/) has a representation of a [directed/undirected graph](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/add-graph-node-names-edge-weights-and-other-attributes.html). I would like to deserialize a graph **with many node and edge attributes** serialized via MATLAB's [save](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) function into Python. I know about [scipy.io.loadmat](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html) and [h5py's File](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/file.html) (for MATLAB v7.3 `save`d files), but neither seems to produce a representation in Python that actually holds intelligible vertex/edge data.

How do I do this? I'm concerned with this and the inverse operation, i.e writing an object from Python to a format MATLAB [load](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) can read. Is there a bytewise data description of a serialized MATLAB object and/or a Graph looks like somewhere?

For example, in MATLAB I could:

```
s = [1 1 2 2 3];
t = [2 4 3 4 4];
G = digraph(s,t);
G.Edges.Rand = rand(size(G.Edges)); % Add an edge attribute
G.Nodes.Val = rand(size(G.Nodes)); % Add a node attribute

save('loadmat.mat', 'G'); % Readable by scipy.io.loadmat
save('h5py.mat', 'G', '-v7.3'); % Readable by h5py.File
```

then, in Python I could read these

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
G0 = loadmat('loadmat.mat')

from h5py import File
G1 = File('h5py.mat')
```

Neither seems to give me the vertex/edge data or am I just missing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `digraph` object is an user-defined object type, not one of the fundamental MATLAB types; no wonder python doesn't understand it. Please note that even MATLAB will not understand the saved object layout if it doesn't have a working definition of the saved object's class, accessible in the path.

You might want to save the adjacency matrix:

```
A = full(adjacency(G));
save('adjacency.mat', 'A');
```

or the incidence matrix:

```
I = full(incidence(G));
save('incidence.mat', 'I');
```

whatever suits you better.

**Late edit**

Another way is to force the object to become a POD (plain old data) that has better chances to be understood by `loadmat`:

```
S = struct(G);
save('pod_digraph.mat', 'S');
```

But mind that you'll have access to all information; the dependent properties will be saved as such; you'll need to recreate the class' interface by yourself in order to maintain consistency (e.g. the adjacency matrix and the incidence matrix can be both constructed on-the-fly from the same internal information, which may look like neither of them). Also, one cannot convert a POD to the original object unless the constructor knows how to do this.

Comment: This won't work because I have attributed graphs (I've clarified on question). Also loadmat is actually able to read the headers on the serialized matlab object and figure out it's a digraph so this must be doable.

Comment: @quine How much effort do you want to put in this? Because IMO there's no way to do this automatically, you either write I/O functions in both languages that will store and retrieve from native objects to a common storage format (and here you chose whatever you want: XML, JSON etc.) or write function in each language that will export directly in the format of the other language (which is messy). The last one requires some hacking and reverse-engineering. Good luck!

Comment: @quine About `loadmat` seeing a `digraph` object in the .mat file, I'd like to give an analogy: you open a file in Notepad, you see it starts with PK, you figure out it's a ZIP archive. But that doesn't mean that you can read the content of the archive in Notepad; you need something else to read the content of the archive.

Comment: I'm willing to write as much code as necessary, but I want to allow matlab users to opaquely save and let me do the lifting on the python side to read/write matlab data. It seems like this is not possible. I understand that loadmat may not understand the data contained within the saved object but it can read the headers which means they know more than I do about serialized matlab objects. What I really need a description of data structure(s), but this seems to be hard to find.

Comment: @quine Hopefully this will help: http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf

Comment: Oh this link is super helpful. Knowing this, perhaps I can save as pod then write a reader !?

Answer (score 0):

The lengthy but certain way to do this is to define a schema for G in something like [Google Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/?hl=en). With that schema you can automatically generate serialiser source code for Python and Java (that you could use in Matlab). This would allow you exchange G between Matlab and Python, or indeed between anything else.

You would probably have to hand write code to translate between how G is stored in Matlab and however protoc chose to represent in Java the message you had defined in the schema. You won't (I'm fairly certain) be able to do Ggpb = G. If both Java and Matlab supported type reflection then you could probably write something neat to do it automatically...